# Win32 doesn't send mouse events to my window, only its parent. why?

Tags: winapi, mouse, message

I have a window that's a CHILD window of another window. For reasons beyond me, NC_HITTEST never gets called on it, no mouse events are called for it (but rather reach its parent window).

Why is that? I want that child window to process his own mouse clicks.

Comment: You say that they reach the parent window, so I presume that you have a handler for those messages for that window. Do you call `DefWindowProc` in that handler?

Comment: Are you using a Static control? If true, be sure to set the `SS_NOTIFY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NC_HITTEST is not likely a message you want to be catching for mouse events.  You want to be catching WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, etc...

Comment: I said not even a HITTEST message arrives at my window- of course I know you don't catch mouse events with this message. I was just wondering why no messages, including the mouse messages you've mentioned above simply never reach my child window, but rather the parent window!